# Insert python object in the Graphs javascript dataobject

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on the Python Django project and have added my HTML in the template folder. Now one of my page needs to render a graph. The data set of the graph is generated from the database and passed to the html.

For a simple graph I have obtained the following code [from HERE](https://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=https://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/line/earthquakes_monthly/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerSet1",
    {
      theme: "theme1",
      title:{
        text: "Restart Count PerDay"
      },
      animationEnabled: true,
      axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "MMM",
        interval:1,
        intervalType: "Date"
      },
      axisY:{
        includeZero: true
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        //lineThickness: 3,
        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414},
        { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }

        ]
      }


      ]
    });

chart.render();
}



    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

**But now I am not able to feed custom data from the python view.**

I tried doing the following:

```
 axisY:{
        includeZero: true
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        //lineThickness: 3,
        dataPoints: {{myobjectforData}}
      }
```

Also,

```
 axisY:{
        includeZero: true
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        //lineThickness: 3,
        dataPoints: "{{myobjectforData}}""
      }
```

I am okay to share more code from my python django template html file.

Comment: so what is your issue? what's the output of {{myobjectforData}} ?

Comment: Nothing. The graph is not even initialize. Can you please help me with some source to do it in the right way??

Comment: @warath-coder Do you need to see more code to catch the issue??